# How to get past problems with virtualenvwrapper on MacOS w/ homebrew python3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have MacOS 10.14.3 with homebrew python 3.6.5_1, and to install virtualenvwrapper I do `python3 -mpip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`. All fine.

Then I source `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` in my `.bashrc`, having set `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=python3` (otherwise you get the MacOS python2, yuck).

Then, to create a virtualenv:

```
% mktmpenv        
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6'
New python executable in ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tmp-a4c44f99827fb6a/bin/python3.6
Also creating executable in ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tmp-a4c44f99827fb6a/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating ~/.virtualenvs/tmp-a4c44f99827fb6a/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating ~/.virtualenvs/tmp-a4c44f99827fb6a/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating ~/.virtualenvs/tmp-a4c44f99827fb6a/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating ~/.virtualenvs/tmp-a4c44f99827fb6a/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating ~/.virtualenvs/tmp-a4c44f99827fb6a/bin/get_env_details
~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tmp-a4c44f99827fb6a/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
~/.local/share/virtualenvs/tmp-a4c44f99827fb6a/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
```

These errors at the end appear to be because the virtualenvwrapper module is only installed in the system (homebrew) python3, not in the virtualenv itself -- so once the virtualenv is activated (i.e. PYTHONPATH is set to exclude the standard path), it can't find virtualenvwrapper:

```
% python3 -c 'import virtualenvwrapper; print(virtualenvwrapper)'
<module 'virtualenvwrapper' (namespace)>
% mkvirtualenv foo
... installs stuff... gives errors...
(foo) % python3 -c 'import virtualenvwrapper'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper'
```

I figure I must have something misconfigured, or I'm missing a step somewhere.

[edit] Further information: `virtualenvwrapper_run_hook`, which runs hooks, loads python by doing

```
$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON -m 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' ...
```

which clearly won't work *in* the virtual env, since that doesn't have `virtualenvwrapper` installed. What am I missing?